# Firebase User Specific Permission Wildcard

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I am getting "User does not have permission to access this object." when I am trying to grant each user permission to all files at the root of their user name in Firebase like so:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/bucketname.appspot.com/o {
    match /users/{userId}/* {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

And from Android here is a sample of the file that I am sending up
[image]

Yet I am getting com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: User does not have permission to access this object.

How can I set the permission differently?

Here is the official example from https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security

```
// Only a user can upload their profile picture, but anyone can view it
match /users/{userId}/profilePicture.png {
  allow read;
  allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

However instead of giving a user access to a particular file, I want to give an authenticated user permission to write to the path after their user Id

Comment: So are you trying to give permission to all users without authentication?

Comment: No with authentication, I am matching the variable userId to the value of their Auth user id.

Comment: I allow read for all but write for authenticated users

Comment: So if I am right, you need to give read access to all, and write access to only with authentication. right?

Comment: Yes and I have updated the question with an example from https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
    service firebase.storage {
  match /b/xxxx.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: glad to help :)